# Amazon SNS into Salesforce

Tags: aws, amazon-aws

Has anyone worked with Amazon SNS to Salesforce?

I see that I can subscribe to a topic which will forward an https request, however, it seems like SNS will only send one https request per message that is published to that topic.  Amazon SNS can add a username and password to the request, but I don't think it can send two requests back to back, i.e.

1. A "login" request, which returns the session id
2. The "real" request, which has the payload that I need.

Anyway that Salesforce REST api can support a single request coming in which includes authentication within it?

Answer (score 1):

Could you instead go from SNS to Lambda and via a salesforce/node package like JSForce or or nforce :: node.js salesforce REST API wrapper and then use that node package to access SF Rest API and send over the payload?

Answer (score -1):

I have prepared a solution for the same , and you can reference it using the below url :

https://github.com/vipul-goyal/Connect-Salesforce-with-AWS-for-IAM-user-assuming-Role-through-STS

Hope it helps you in your pursuit on connecting AWS using apex.

Thanks,

Vipul

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE!  Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: looking at your github repo, your implementation is far from the best practice of using Named/Ext Creds and including authorization (token acquisition/exchange) in there.  NC/EC support AWS Sig V4 _and_ AWS STS out of the box.

Comment: Hi @identigral , I would just like to inform you that I know Signature V4 is available out of the box with named credentials , but the issue we face is that Amazon sends 403 for token expiry but salesforce expects a 400 or 401 to refresh token. So we are unable to proceed ahead once the token expires , as this is a standard API from Amazon,we cannot the API gateway status codes for expired tokens , thats why I gave a custom solution to it. I agree to the point that few values are static in my implementation, but it's for reference.If I am able to put my point my forward,please upvote my effort

Comment: Where does the refresh come in? This isn't oAuth. When you call out from SF to AWS, the callout obtains a fresh token every time.

Comment: When we use Named Credential , we only get a new token when the old token expires and salesforce get the response as 400 or 401 ,this is documented by Salesforce itself, but AWS sends a 403 when the token has expired.

Comment: Salesforce Documentation for signature V4 : 
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.nc_create_edit_awssig4_ext_cred.htm&type=5

Please check the section - Obtain Temporary IAM Credentials via STS